# C Functions not executing in order

Tags: c, execution

I know there may be questions similar to this, its just that they are in C++, and I don't know if they are the same. I have some code

```
void BuildApp(char *AppName)
{
        char *cmd;
        cmd = combine("mkdir ./Projects/", AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, "/Package/");
        // Make the package dir.
        system(cmd);
        cmd = "";
        cmd = combine("mkdir ./Projects/", AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, "/Package/DEBIAN");
        system(cmd);
        cmd = "";
        cmd = combine("mkdir ./Projects/", AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, "/Package/Applications");
        system(cmd);
        cmd = "";
        cmd = combine("mkdir ./Projects/", AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, "/Package/Applications/");
        cmd = combine(cmd, AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, ".app");
        system(cmd);
        cmd = "";
        cmd = combine("mkdir ./Projects/", AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, "/Package/Applications/");
        cmd = combine(cmd, AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, ".app/Inc");
        system(cmd);
        cmd = "";
        cmd = combine("cp ./Projects/", AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, "/Assets/app.icon.png ./Projects/");
        cmd = combine(cmd, AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, "/Package/Applications/");
        cmd = combine(cmd, AppName);
        cmd = combine(cmd, ".app/Icon.png");
        system(cmd);
        printf("Building application...");
        cmd = "";
        cmd = combine("cd ./Projects/", AppName);
        system(cmd);
        printf(cmd);
        cmd = "";
        cmd = combine("gcc App.c -o ", AppName);
        printf(cmd);system(cmd);
        system(cmd);
}
```

but it appears to be executing out of order. This is being run on Linux (Actually, cygwin), and compiled with GCC. For some reason, the `system();` function that should be executing the GCC compile action is executing before the `cd` command, giving me this output:

```
gcc: App.c: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files
Building application...
cd ./Projects/Sample
```

But, after the `cd` statement (which I printed to check the order they where getting executed in), the GCC compile command isn't executing, leaving me with an uncompiled App.c, and errors on program execution.
 Any help as to why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full source code (or enough of it to reproduce the problem) ?

Comment: Why don't you use semi-colons in the system() syscall ? Like "mkdir .../... ; cd ... ; gcc ..."

Comment: In my main app file, I'm just checking to make sure there is a command line argument, and executing `BuildApp();` with `argv[1]` as the char parameter. Here is the `combine();` function code: `char buffer[100];
char *combine(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    sprintf(buffer, "%s%s", str1, str2);
    return buffer;
}`

Comment: @HQarroum Would that make the program run faster, or just neaten the code?

Comment: @Matthew Nickson Both, and this will ensure every commands are executed in the right order, and pay attention to your combine function you're not checking if the src size of your char* fits into a 100-byte string, you could get a stackoverflow here.

Comment: @HQarroum, [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), not a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Comment: @dbaupp Let's call it the right way : A Stack buffer overflow ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Stack-based_exploitation

Comment: @MatthewNickson Why not write a shell script instead of a C program? If you _must_ use C, write all of the commands into a file (such as `/tmp/myscript.sh`) and then call `system()` once, something like `system("sh /tmp/myscript.sh");`. If the script fails, you can examine the script, modify it until it works, and then modify the C to write a working script. Much easier IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two "issues":

- The output you're seeing is both from `stderr` (the GCC error message) and `stdout` (the rest of it). You're inferring that the order in which these messages appear on your terminal is the same as the order the code that generated them ran - you can't rely on that. `stdout` is usually buffered, while `stderr` generally isn't, so the order in which they appear on your screen isn't an indicator of the order of execution of your code.
- The `system("cd whatever");` call is a bug. It spawns a new shell, that shell changes directories and... promptly exists. It has no side-effect whatsoever on the parent process or the subsequent `system` calls. You need to use `chdir` in the parent process, or do the `cd` and `gcc` in the same `system` call.

Answer (score 2):

Each `system` command is executed as a seperate process. You change the working of the fresh process which then just ends.. It has no effect on the next executed process.

Use `system("cd dir; command");`